# EditText disable the default editable and keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I created an android application with EditText and when load it auto start the editable keyboard.
I want manually when the user click the edittext then start the edit and keyboard....

Answer (score 2):

change your manifest file as like this

```
<activity android:name=".yourActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"/>
```

if you want more information you can check developer doc  [android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

set this attribute in your layout in which you set the edittext

```
           android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```